# Get data from Yahoo finance api

Tags: json, api, yahoo, finance

I am trying use the Yahoo finance api to get a real time report of

- Major world market Indices
- futures
- Commodities
  and finally currencies.

exactly whats shown on this site: http://liveindex.org

the yahoo finance api documentation is so crappy, and my research has yielded nothing so far, please help me with the yql query for this or other alternative source for this data

Comment: I would recommend using a web scraper if you want data from Yahoo. Their documentation is terrible, and a lot of their endpoints do not even work. You can also try out a service like Quandl which offers this data in a nice format (and is well-documented), and most of it is for free.

Comment: @puzzled123, thanks will check Quandl out, glory days of yahoo are so done